# Can we add more than one validator in from one node on substrate?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I heard that we can **add only one validator from one node on polkadot**(Heard this from one of the substrate core developer). But , In substrate we are able to add more than one validator from same node which leads to below problem---- 
After adding 3 validators from same node(in staging) the finalization has been stopped and blocks are not being produced.

1. How to solve the above problem?
2. how polkadot is able to stop adding many validators from same node?(If the above **bold** text is true)

Comment: ok expert in substrate development ... is there any limit on adding validators from one node??? I have got this info from substrate core developer named wei tang

Comment: I'm a newbie... I think your questions are not possible in production. why do you care?

Comment: We have created a blockchain with substrate and facing this issue in staging mode